# S_ISREG macro undefined

Tags: c, curl, macros

Questions

- Are the posix macros S_ISREG, S_ISDIR etc linux only? I need to find out because i am trying to compile [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) and it is trying to use them on windows

  What include file can i use to access them on windows.

This is the offending code

```
/*we ignore file size for char/block devices, sockets etc*/
if(S_ISREG(fileinfo.st_mode))
   uploadfilesize= fileinfo.st_size;
}
```

and it causes an error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _S_ISREG referenced in function _operate file tool_operate.obj
```

They are referenced in the following questions

- [How to use S_ISREG() and S_ISDIR() POSIX Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989431/how-to-use-s-isreg-and-s-isdir-posix-macros)
- [Differentiate between a unix directory and file in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036625/differentiate-between-a-unix-directory-and-file-in-c)
- [Problem reading directories in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478492/problem-reading-directories-in-c)

Apparently S_ISREG() is part of a bunch of posix macros and is apparently supposed to tell us if a file is a "regular file" but all the examples I found had linux specific include files.

Comment: "Are the posix macros S_ISREG, S_ISDIR etc linux only?" No, you say it yourself in that question: "posix macros". They are on every POSIX-compliant system.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get a pre-compiled Windows version? Shouldn't be too hard to find. Otherwise, how do you configure CURL for building? What environment (Visual Studio, Cygwin, MinGW?)

Comment: Funnily enough, nobody seems to have noticed that the link error is about the underscore-prefixed _S_ISREG, which is why curl's #define does not fire: most likely S_ISREG is already defined and references _S_ISREG. My guess is that including <sys/stat.h> would enable it to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such thing on windows, you can use the FindFirstFile, FindNextFile win32 api, the return structure contains something similar but not the same.

If you use gcc/mingw library they have a stat() simulation. You need to include sys/stat.h for that macro.

Comment: I have the same S_ISREG undefine problem, but I don't understand the answer.  I can see that sys/stat.h is already being included in setup_once.h, which should be included by setup.h already.  Exactly what do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: which compiler you are using?

Comment: MSVC.  I got it to compiled by moving the #include setup_once.h statements right before the S_ISREG definition so it will pick up the S_IFREG defn.  Not sure if it's the right way to fix.

Comment: if you use MSVC, you should use the windows API instead of the unix stat(). e.g.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: To be clear, sys/stat.h and the stat function do exist on Windows (at least VS2017). What's missing is the S_ISREG macros (and similar macros like S_ISDIR). However, it is possible to add them yourself. See my answer below. If you can do this in a header file that includes sys/stat.h (e.g. "mystat.h"), then you can use portable code using the stat function in your source files, without having to do an 'ifdef' for operating-system-specific APIs like  FindFirstFile each time you need to check file status. (It is puzzling that Microsoft included sys/stat.h but only some of its contents.)

Answer (score 14):

Currently curl 7.21.5 defines in setup.h this:

```
#if !defined(S_ISREG) && defined(S_IFMT) && defined(S_IFREG)
#define S_ISREG(m) (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)
#endif
```

Comment: In VS2017, I can use MSVC compiler and use S_ISREG using the above code. This should be marked correct answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I found a modification of it that did work in VS2017. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

After having inspected Microsoft's sys/stat.h, I found that the following modification of @OliverZendel's answer worked for me, with Visual Studio 2017, and hopefully on other compilers as well:

```
// Windows does not define the S_ISREG and S_ISDIR macros in stat.h, so we do.
// We have to define _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES 1 before #including sys/stat.h
// in order for Microsoft's stat.h to define names like S_IFMT, S_IFREG, and S_IFDIR,
// rather than just defining  _S_IFMT, _S_IFREG, and _S_IFDIR as it normally does.
#define _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES 1
#include <sys/stat.h>
#if !defined(S_ISREG) && defined(S_IFMT) && defined(S_IFREG)
  #define S_ISREG(m) (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)
#endif
#if !defined(S_ISDIR) && defined(S_IFMT) && defined(S_IFDIR)
  #define S_ISDIR(m) (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

On windows try adding the underscore (`_S_ISREG`). In MinGW's lib the `S_ISREG` macro is also accessible in `<sys/stat.h>`

Maybe you should just check your configuration macros.

Comment: its not my code. Its part of curl code that generates errors during link step in tool_operate.c .

Comment: What include file is needed or what library should be linked?

Comment: Where did you find _S_ISREG ? Is this MinGW specific? VS2010 does not have it

Comment: S_ISREG is an emulation of POSIX macro. For Win32 one should use MSVC/MSDN-specified APIs.  I've found the underscore using a text-mode search in all of the MinGW's headers.

Comment: I guess the underscore is in MSVC's linker (.C file compiled with cdecl convention will use underscores in symbol names).

Comment: After having inspected Microsoft's sys/stat.h for VS2017, it appears to me that neither S_ISREG nor _S_ISREG will be defined by it. However, enough constants like _S_IFMT and _S_IFREG are defined (and also S_IFMT and S_IFREG if _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES is #defined to 1) to allow you to define your own S_ISREG. See my answer below.