What is the Windows equivalent of S_IFREG?
I'm writing some code in C and ran into an issue- even though I have the sys/stats.h header defined, when I use S_IFREG, it gives me the error "use of undeclared identifier S_IFREG. After googling, it tells me that this isn't something that can be used on Windows, which is what I'm on.I couldn't find a clear answer of what would be the equivalent on windows, so I was wondering if anyone could help me. Here is my code:
int function( command_t* p_cmd ) {


char path[MAX_ARG_LEN];
    strcpy(path, getenv("PATH"));

    char *token = strtok(path, ":");

    while(token != NULL){
        char parameter[MAX_ARG_LEN];
        strcpy(parameter, token);
        strcat(parameter, "/");
        strcat(parameter, p_cmd->argv[0]);

        struct stat buffer;
        int exists;

        exists = stat(parameter, &buffer);
        if(exists == 0 && (S_IFREG & buffer.st_mode)){
            strcpy(p_cmd->argv[0] , parameter);
            return 1; 
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

    return 0;
}

These are the headers im using, and I cant alter them to add additional libraries.
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

I also cannot alter the parameters or use any extensions.

Stat under windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-170. You would check against _S_IFREG with a leading _.

"... tells me that this isn't something that can be used on Windows," --> It is not an OS thing, (Windows), but a compiler one.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11238918/20017547 and https://www.davekb.com/search.php?target=GetFileAttributes

Answer moved from edit to question:

Essentially, modern POSIX-compliant systems need S_IFMT and S_IFREG values, but POSIX.1-1990 doesn't and actually prohibits you from including them. In my first piece of code, I am manually masking to check the file:
(S_IFREG & buffer.st_mode)

but macros provided by  POSIX-compliant systems already does this for you, so the code should be:
S_ISREG(buffer.st_mode)

